# Product over integral representations and steepest descents

Tags: statistical-mechanics, integration, approximations, spin-models

Suppose we have a product of Dirac or Heaviside functions in the context of a spin model and we use an integral representation to express these in order to do some manipulations, more specifically averaging over Gaussian variables or taking replicas. For example something like
\begin{equation}
\Omega = \prod_{k=1}^N \delta\left(\sigma_k \sum_j \sigma_j -1 \right) = \prod_{k=1}^N \int_{-i\infty}^{i\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}\lambda_k}{2\pi i} \, e^{\lambda_k(\sigma_k \sum_j \sigma_j - 1)}
\end{equation}
that we are planning on approximating using steepest descent down the road as $N\to \infty$.

At this stage, it seems like a common thing in spin glass literature to say that for the steepest descent the maxima will be identical in all $k$ so $\lambda_k = \lambda$.

Then my question is the following: what happens with the integration? Should I do it just once, or once $N$ times? Should I have the $2\pi i$ denominator raised to the power $N$? This is actually even more important for Heavisides where the integral representation has a $1/\lambda_k$ factor in the integrand.

Honestly this sounds very basic but the spin glass literature is filled with what I find to be very few number of steps in replica calculations and such.

For a better context of the overall question, it is motivated by

> Bray, A. J., & Moore, M. A. (1981). *Metastable states in the solvable spin glass model.* Journal of Physics A: Mathematical and General, 14(9), L377–L383. doi:10.1088/0305-4470/14/9/012

more specifically equations (8) to (10) where they do precisely this over the $n$ replicas and the differential actually vanishes and so does the $(2\pi i)^{-1}$ factor...

Similarly in

> Bray, A. J., & Moore, M. A. (1980). *Metastable states in spin glasses.* Journal of Physics C: Solid State Physics, 13(19), L469–L476. doi:10.1088/0022-3719/13/19/002

between equations (4) and (6) the integral is seemingly taken out of the product with no exponent $N$ in sight...

Any help would be much appreciated, I feel like I'm being a bit dumb about all this.

Thanks!